Pop-ups do not appear in ArcGIS Online
I am working on a dashboard in ArcGIS Online. On the webmap there is a point layer and a polygon layer and I have enabled pop-ups on both these layers. The pop-ups appear as expected for the point layer - the points turn blue to show they have been selected and the pop-up appears (as per the first image). However they are not working for the polygon layer and I just get this circle icon to show that something is loading, but no pop-up appears and the feature does not become selected (second image).



To clarify, the pop up not working is occurring in the map viewer while creating a map, not in an app that is consuming the map?

@Baltok pop-ups do not show when clicking on a feature in the layer in the web map or in the app. This is despite the fact I have enabled them in the layer properties in the web map.

Hm, I'm not sure what's going on in that case - sounds like a bug. Things to test/check:  1. Do other polygon layers pop ups work. 2. Is there something funky in the attributes. 3. Is there a field like Date Only in the layer that AGOL doesn't recognize well. 4. Can you upload your polygon layer in a different format and see if that changes things.
